# How Do I Create an html email button that will send back to me an emailed response?

Tags: html, email

I have a small ecommerce business and from time to time a customer will say that they never ordered the item and I am forced to refund their money due to lack of any confirmation from the customer as to his actually placing the order.

I would like to add either an hmtl button or any sort of tool to the emails that i sent you with the customer's receipt.  The customer will get the email with his receipt and also within the email will be a button ("I approve This Transaction") for him to click on that will send me back a confirmation email.

Please advise.

Thanks,
Don

Comment: Do some research yourself and then try some code before asking on StackOverflow for help. This site is not a code request site.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways to do this.

1. With a `mailto:` link, this would open the users default email client where they would have to send the email as an extra step.
2. URL parameter in a normal href/button link (ie: www.yoursite.com/yourpage.php?email=their@email.com). You would link to a webpage (yourpage.php) that would pass that URL parameter (in this example "email", but can be any other info you pass through) you can then parse that URL parameter in your webpage and have it email you automatically based on that info.

Option 2 is the way to go, but requires some coding knowledge (PHP for example). Also, in order to set up unique URL parameters, you'll need a system that uses merge tags to create unique values for each email you send. I'd suggest you should use a transactional email service provider for this.